# CSS login & dashboard messy?

Tags: angular

I have a huge problem with my CSS not working with my Angular project.

When I log in on the login page

```
username = toto 
password = 123
```

I created a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/github/kora1348/salma?file=src/styles.css).

[image]

I gotta get that view

[image]

Unfortunately I get this view, I don't understand what is wrong? The CSS code is perfect, it's just Angular that blocks, but I don't understand. :-(

Do you have an idea please. I've been stuck since yesterday.

[image]

***styles.css***

This is the login

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    
    body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #444;
    }
    
    .container {
    position: relative;
    width: 70vw;
    height: 80vh;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .container::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #4a60df, #085224);
    z-index: 6;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: 1s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .signin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    z-index: 5;
    }
    
    form {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 238px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    form.sign-in-form {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    }
    
    .title {
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #4a4ddf;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    
    .input-field {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 2px solid #4a6ddf;
    border-radius: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    }
    
    .input-field i {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .input-field input {
    flex: 5;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #444;
    }
    
    .btn {
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: #4a8bdf;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px 5px 10px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
    background: #3c3ec0;
    }
    
    .icon-text {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .icon-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .item-icon {
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    }
    
    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .item-icon:hover {
    color: #4a59df;
    border-color: #724adf;
    }
    
    .panels-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    .panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 35%;
    min-width: 238px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 6;
    }
    
    .left-panel {
    pointer-events: none;
    }
    
    .content {
    color: #fff;
    transition: 1.1s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    
    .panel h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    .panel p {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    }
    
    .image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 80px
    }
    
    .left-panel .image,
    .left-panel .content {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    }
    
    .right-panel .image,
    .right-panel .content {
    transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
    .signin_item_block {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 40%;
    min-width: 238px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    }
    
    .signin_item_block.sign-in-block-form {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition-delay: 1s;
    }
    
    
    /*Responsive*/
    
    @media (max-width:779px) {
    .container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:635px) {
    .container::before {
    display: none;
    }
    form {
    width: 80%;
    }
    .signin_item_block.sign-in-block-form {
    display: none;
    }
    .container.sign-up-mode2 form.sign-in-block-form {
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    }
    .container.sign-up-mode2 form.sign-in-form {
    display: none;
    }
    .panels-container {
    display: none;
    }
    }
    
    @media (max-width:320px) {
    form {
    width: 90%;
    }
    }
```

***online.component.css***

This is the dashboard.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

ul {
padding: 0;
}


/* Hamburger Menu */

.hamburger-menu {
position: relative;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
margin: 0 15px;
}

.label-hamburger-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
cursor: pointer;
transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.label-hamburger-menu .bar {
width: 40px;
height: 4px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 1px;
transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.label-hamburger-menu .bar:not(:first-child) {
margin-top: 5px;
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu {
display: none;
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu:checked+.label-hamburger-menu {
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(180deg);
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu:checked+.label-hamburger-menu .bar {
width: 30px;
transform: rotateY(180deg) rotateX(360deg);
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu:checked+.label-hamburger-menu .bar:first-child {
transform: translateY(9px) rotate(-45deg);
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu:checked+.label-hamburger-menu .bar:nth-child(2) {
opacity: 0;
}

#checkbox-hamburger-menu:checked+.label-hamburger-menu .bar:nth-child(3) {
transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(45deg);
}


/* Home Section */

.home-section {
position: relative;
background: #f3f6f2;
height: 100vh;
left: 260px;
width: calc(100% - 260px);
transition: all 0.5s ease;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.home-section .home-header {
height: 122px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
background-color: #1bb16c;
/* #bbe7aa */
}

.home-section .home-header .title {
color: #fff;
font-size: 22px;
font-weight: 600;

}




/* .home-section .home-view {
flex-grow: 1;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: column;
color: #fff;
} */


/* Sidebar */

.sidebar {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 260px;
background: #fff;
z-index: 100;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close {
width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar .logo-details img {
height: 50px;
width: 80%;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links {
height: 100%;
width: 260px;
padding-bottom: 150px;
overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar .nav-links::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li {
list-style: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links>li {
position: relative;
width: fit-content;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover {
background: #eaeaea;
}


/* Dropdown Title */

.sidebar .nav-links .dropdown-title {
width: 260px;
overflow: hidden;
transition: all 0.52s ease;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
position: relative;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links .dropdown-title {
width: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li i {
height: 50px;
min-width: 60px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: #004a65;
font-size: 20px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover i,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active i {
color: #004a65;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu i.arrow {
transform: rotate(-180deg);
}


/* a Tag */

.sidebar .nav-links li a {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
text-decoration: none;
width: 100%;
}


/* Link Name */

.sidebar .nav-links li a .link_name {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
color: #004a65;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover a .link_name,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active a .link_name {
color: #004a65;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li a .link_name {
pointer-events: none;
}


/* Sub Menu */

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu {
background: #fff;
display: none;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li.showMenu .sub-menu {
display: block;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu a {
color: #004a65;
font-size: 15px;
white-space: nowrap;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
padding: 7px 0px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
padding-left: 10px;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover a,
.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li.active a {
color: green;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 600;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:hover {
background: #e8f5f9;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:not(:first-child) {
padding: 5px 60px;
border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu li:last-child {
padding: 5px 60px;
border-top: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: -10px;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 0;
border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
opacity: 0;
display: block;
pointer-events: none;
transition: 0s;
overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li {
padding: 6px 15px;
width: 200px;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu {
top: 0;
opacity: 1;
pointer-events: auto;
transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
display: none;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu .link_name {
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 600;
display: block;
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu li:first-child {
background: #fff;
pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li .sub-menu.blank {
pointer-events: auto;
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}

.sidebar .nav-links li:hover .sub-menu.blank,
.sidebar .nav-links li.active .sub-menu.blank {
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close~.home-section {
left: 60px;
width: calc(100% - 60px);
}

.sidebar.sidebar-close .logo-details img {
width: 37px;
height: 50px;
transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-3px);
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
.sidebar.sidebar-close .nav-links li .sub-menu {
display: none;
}
}
```

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `container` class from `<div class="home-content">` in corporate.component.html:
Working Link is
[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-yuxflr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fviews%2Fonline%2Fviews%2Fadministration%2Fviews%2Fcorporate-action%2Fcorporate-action.component.html)

[image: Current UI design]

let me know if you require further assistance for design

Comment: I opened your link, unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I still have the same display problem.

Comment: your problem related to ui is not solved?

Comment: M. DaveNo, unfortunately I opened your link and I still have the same problem. I am desperate. If you have a solution, I'm really interested.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

1. CSS from "container" class: width: 100vw --> width: 100%; width: 70vw --> width: 70%
2. app-root {width: 100%}